# Python 3.5: Web-scraping with Stripping html codes

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am scraping the web content but stuck with a problem. After a series of processing to strip the scope that I want, I cannot strip the html code to make it plain text in a list. I have tried using the function of replace, re.compile and join (try to change the list to text for stripping). All doesn't work as they are designed for string or pops out errors when running.

Could anyone give me some hint how to do that. For example, I want the output from the following code change from

```
<p class="course-d-title">Instructor</p>
```

to `Instructor`.

```
import tkinter as tk
import re

def test():
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    import urllib.request
    from urllib.parse import urljoin

    '''for layer 0'''        
    url_text = 'http://www.scs.cuhk.edu.hk/en/part-time/accounting-and-finance/accounting-and-finance/fundamental-accounting/162-610441-01'
    resp = urllib.request.urlopen(url_text)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(resp, from_encoding=resp.info().get_param('charset'))
    a = soup.find_all('p')

    k=0
    for item in a[:]:
        if 'Instructor' in item:
            a=a[k:]
            break
        k+=1

    j=0
    for item in a[:]:
        if 'Enquiries' in item:
            a=a[:j-1]
            break
        j+=1

    for i in range(0,a.__len__()):
        print (a[i])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    test()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `.text` to extract text from bs4 element

```
>>> a = soup.find_all('p')
>>> data = [ item for item in a if 'Instructor' in item]
[<p class="course-d-title">Instructor</p>]

>>> data[0].text
'Instructor'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to take the Name of Instructor and Enquiries phone number also, below code can help you.

```
 import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url_text = 'http://www.scs.cuhk.edu.hk/en/part-time/accounting-and-finance/accounting-and-finance/fundamental-accounting/162-610441-01'
resp = requests.get(url_text)
soup = BeautifulSoup(resp.text, 'html.parser')
a = soup.find_all('p')
for i in a:
    if 'Instructor' in i:
        print i.get_text(), "Name is  " + soup.find('p',{'class':'course-d-val'}).get_text()
    elif 'Enquiries' in i:
        print i.get_text(), "The number is " + soup.find('span',{'class':'enq-phone'}).get_text() ,"The Fax is " + soup.find('span',{'class':'enq-fax'}).get_text()
```

This code will give you printout as

```
Instructor Name is  Ms. MACK Shui San
Enquiries The number is 3943 9046 The Fax is 2770 8275
```

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot and I do like your idea of using keyword search. And could you explain further how you do that in case of "Instructor". It seems 'course-d-val' is not unique to Instructor. It happens in a few more places. How can the system know you are talking about the 'course-d-val' right after Instructor?

Comment: @CL.L it is simple I am looking for first 'course-d-val' since I am using find function not findAll,basically these kind of things depends on the html of website

Answer (score 0):

I found the following code, in a simpler and more flexible way, can achieve the same purposes but allow keyword search:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests   

url_text = 'http://www.scs.cuhk.edu.hk/en/part-time/accounting-and-finance/accounting-and-finance/fundamental-accounting/162-610441-01'

resp = requests.get(url_text)
soup = BeautifulSoup(resp.text, 'html.parser')    
print (soup.find(text="Instructor").findNext('p').text)
```